# Web API - Set each thread with the HttpRequestMessage id?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api coded in c#.

The web api uses functionality which is shared with other in-house components.
it depends on single threaded flows and uses thread local storage to store objects, and session information.
Please don't say if it's good or bad, that's what I have to deal with.

In the web api I've implemented a custom message handler (DelagatingHandler) with SendAsync

```
protected async override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

which is based on TPL and sometimes switches threads, and when this happens, my thread based functionality gets messed up, since I'm losing the thread context and all data assigned to it.

My idea is to uniquely identify the HttpRequestMessage,
I think using the correlation id should be sufficient for it

```
var requestId = request.GetCorrelationId();
```

But I want to store the correlation Id of the HttpRequestMessage per each thread that is allocated in the Task.

So my question is basically if I can identify a thread that's being allocated under a specific Task and allocate the id to it?

Comment: You want to map a request (correlation id) with the *first* thread that it hits?

Comment: I actually want to identify the request, from any thread in it's context, I assume the correlation Id is assigned with the first thread allocated to the requested.

Comment: But regardless of context flow, after you `await` inside a method, you're still inside the same `HttpRequestMessage`, but the thread may differ. I'm probably still not understand this thoroughly

Comment: Yes that's exactly my issue, if the thread changes I'm losing my scope (custom scope that is), and I want to be able to tell if the thread I'm currently at is already assigned to what I consider to be a valid context, which is the HttpRequestMessage.context. makes sense?\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For context related problems, you can use [`CallContext.LogicalSetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.logicalsetdata(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`CallContext.LogicalGetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.logicalgetdata(v=vs.110).aspx), which is merely an `IDictionary<string, object>` which flows between contexts, and has a copy-on-write (shallow copy) semantics.

Since your data is immutable (according to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969060(v=vs.118).aspx)), you can map your correlation id to your threads managed thread id:

```
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                         HttpRequestMessage request, 
                         CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var correlationId = request.GetCorrelationId();
    var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

    CallContext.LogicalSetData(correlationId.ToString(), threadId);
}
```

And later retrieve if to make sure you're on a "valid thread".

A good read on call context with `async-await` can be found [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).

Comment: Thank you Yuval for your response, I will try it and keep you posted.